# Ubuntu Webserver with Nginx Issue

Tags: server, permissions, php, nginx

I am creating a website on an ubuntu server using nginx. I set it up so that when you go to it is ask for a user name and password. I used this command:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd username
```

I then ran this command to make changes to this file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

The files looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  server_name (put IP address here); # Change this to your FQDN.

  location /munki_repo/ {
    alias /usr/local/munki_repo/;
    autoindex off;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
  }
}
```

So after doing that and and of course setting up the files/directories. When I go to `ipaddress/munki_repo` in the web browser and enter the correct username and password it gives me the following error:

```
403 Forbidden

nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
```

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? this is the first time I have used nginx.

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is that without an `index.html` file to serve (or a corresponding `try_files` and `index` directive) that NGINX will try and do a directory listing, which is forbidden in your config (`autoindex off;`).

To override this, you should be doing at least one of ***two things***:

1. Use a `try_files $uri /index.html` directive in your specialized location block.  This makes sure to not try a directory listing, but if there's a failure to find the correct URI, it will default to the root site's index page.
2. Make sure you have an `index.htm` OR `index.html` OR `index.php` file in each location (this does not apply for `proxy_pass` or `fastcgi_pass` requests which pass requests to a backend server for handling).  Each directory should have an index file that is of a name that is listed in the `index` directive in your config.

(You've discovered #2 yourself, however this is a more comprehensive reply)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I made the mistake of not putting an index.html file in the directory, once I did that everything was working.

Comment: Sounds good, but this answer is pretty simple.  Note that I gave an expanded answer with my suggestions on handling this in the future.